# How to use folders with spaces in SAS x "copy ..."?

Tags: sas, copy

In sas I need to copye file from a place to another but that file is located in a folder with spaces wich poses problems.

Here is what I want to do:

```
x "copy \\aaa\b c d\eee.pdf \\fff\ggg.pdf";
```

because of the spaces between b c and d it doesn't work.

I know I can do

```
x 'copy \\aaa\"b c d"\eee.pdf \\fff\ggg.pdf';
```

But the name of my files will use macro variables thus I need the double quotes around the copy statement.

Is there a way to escape doubles quotes in the copy statement? something like this for example (except % are not working)

```
x "copy \\aaa\%"b c d%"\eee.pdf \\fff\ggg.pdf";
```

EDIT
I also tried cats:

```
x cats("copy \\aaa\",'"b c d"',"\eee.pdf \\fff\ggg.pdf");
```

Comment: some great answers in this thread!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `x` with `%sysexec` and you won't need the quotes.

```
%sysexec copy "\\aaa\b c d\eee.pdf" "\\fff\ggg.pdf";
```

Answer (score 2):

Double up your quotes!

```
x "copy ""\\aaa\b c d\eee.pdf"" \\fff\ggg.pdf";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `QUOTE()` function. It will properly double the internal quotes in the string that you are trying to quote.

```
x %sysfunc(quote(copy "\\aaa\b c d\eee.pdf" "\\fff\ggg.pdf"));
```